# Zigbee beaconing vs non beaconing

Tags: networking, embedded-linux, zigbee

When using a non beaconing Zigbee network, I know that the 802.15.4 spec defines the use of CSMA-CA to control when two devices get access to a channel to make sure no two nodes "step on each others toes" so to speak. My understanding is that very simply, it requires each node to "listen before talking". Is that correct? Is there more information on the Zigbee implementation of this? In other words, where do I go to learn more about how to program a Zigbee chip to implement the same?

Also, if i have 20 end nodes sending data asynchronously to one coordinator, is the channel access mechanism enough to ensure that they do not broadcast at the same time and flood the coordinator? If five nodes (for example) attempt to broadcast at the same time, how will mutual exclusion be ensured? Where can I get some details on that?

Thanks
Rishi

Answer (score 1):

The maximum size of a 802.15.4 packet is 1024 bits of payload. So the maximum duration of the frame (running in standard 250kbps rate on the 2.4GHz band) is about 5ms when you take preamble etc into account.  If your end devices are polling at 1 poll/second it should easily manage 20 end nodes I think. If it gets too much the exponential backoff should ease the collision rate.

I'm sure you've seen these when searching, but just in case:

- http://www.prismmodelchecker.org/casestudies/zigbee.php
- http://www.dagstuhl.de/Materials/Files/07/07101/07101.FruthMatthias.Slides.pdf
- http://www-public.it-sudparis.eu/~gauthier/Tools/802_15_4_MAC_PHY_Usage.pdf

Comment: I'm looking at possibly 200 polls per end device per minute but the data could be more than one packet per poll. Would you recommend beaconing in that case or should non beaconing work fine as well?

Thanks for your response